# I created a graph with Petgraph using structs as nodes but I can't change the values of the struct after the nodes have been put together

Tags: rust

At the moment, my nodes are made of a struct which hold a name and a value.
Later the graph is created.
I want to change the value of certain nodes. I also want the struct to hold many other categories at some point.

The problem is that I'm not able to change the values of the struct in the node **after** the nodes have been put together in the graph.

In the code below, I have 3 nodes and two of them are connected to a main node. I find the children of the main node and then for each children, I try to change the values of their struct to an arbitrary value (for testing).

```rust
use petgraph::stable_graph::StableGraph;

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
struct ControlBloc {
    name: String,
    value: u32,
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug, Default)]
struct Arcs {
    speed_arcs: f32,
    bandwidth: f32,
    state_bandwidth: f32,
}

fn create_bloc(name: String, value: u32) -> ControlBloc {
    ControlBloc { name, value }
}

fn main() {
    let mut graph = StableGraph::<&ControlBloc, &Arcs>::new();
    let m = &create_bloc(String::from("Main"), 10);
    let b1 = &create_bloc(String::from("sub1"), 20);
    let b2 = &create_bloc(String::from("sub2"), 30);
    let main = graph.add_node(m);
    let sub1 = graph.add_node(b1);
    let sub2 = graph.add_node(b2);

    graph.add_edge(
        main,
        sub1,
        &Arcs {
            speed_arcs: 1.0,
            bandwidth: 1.02,
            state_bandwidth: 0.0,
        },
    );
    graph.add_edge(
        main,
        sub2,
        &Arcs {
            speed_arcs: 2.0,
            bandwidth: 2.02,
            state_bandwidth: 0.0,
        },
    );

    let neighb = graph.neighbors(main).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for i in 0..neighb.len() {
        let &mut nod = graph.node_weight_mut(neighb[i]).unwrap();
        let ar = *graph
            .edge_weight(graph.find_edge(main, neighb[i]).unwrap())
            .unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", nod);
        nod.value = 10; // ##########  Problem Here :(  ################
        println!("{:?}", nod);
        println!("{:?}", ar);
    }
}
```

Whatever I try to do I get as an error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `nod.value`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:56:9
   |
51 |         let &mut nod = graph.node_weight_mut(neighb[i]).unwrap();
   |                  --- consider changing this binding's type to be: `&mut ControlBloc`
...
56 |         nod.value = 10; // ##########  Problem Here :(  ################
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `nod` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

Is it telling me that it is actually impossible to change the values once they have been set in the graph? Because if I want to print them then that's fine but it is a bit useless if I can't do anything about them.

One solution that I could think of would be to create a copy of the node with the value I want to change and when I create it, I put the correct value and then replace the old node with the new node by replacing the edges in the graph. That, however, seems rather long of a solution if there is a way to fix the original code.

Comment: You should probably be storing `ControlBloc`s and `Arcs`s in the graph by value, not references to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that your graph does not **own** the values, but instead it only holds references to them.

You can't manipulate references, you should either hold a `&mut`, which is often problematic, or transfer the ownership to the graph.

Here's my code, which works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut graph = StableGraph::<ControlBloc, Arcs>::new();
    let m = create_bloc(String::from("Main"), 10);
    let b1 = create_bloc(String::from("sub1"), 20);
    let b2 = create_bloc(String::from("sub2"), 30);
    let main = graph.add_node(m);
    let sub1 = graph.add_node(b1);
    let sub2 = graph.add_node(b2);

    graph.add_edge(
        main,
        sub1,
        Arcs {
            speed_arcs: 1.0,
            bandwidth: 1.02,
            state_bandwidth: 0.0,
        },
    );
    graph.add_edge(
        main,
        sub2,
        Arcs {
            speed_arcs: 2.0,
            bandwidth: 2.02,
            state_bandwidth: 0.0,
        },
    );

    let neighb = graph.neighbors(main).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for i in 0..neighb.len() {
        let nod = graph.node_weight_mut(neighb[i]).unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", nod);
        nod.value = 10;
        println!("{:?}", nod);
        let ar = graph
            .edge_weight(graph.find_edge(main, neighb[i]).unwrap())
            .unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", ar);
    }
}
```

Please not how I changed `StableGraph::<&ControlBloc, &Arcs>::new()` to `StableGraph::<ControlBloc, Arcs>::new()`, which could be ultimatly shortened to `StableGraph::new()`, because Rust is able to infer the types.

Also note, that I moved the `let ar = ...` code down, because else you will get another borrow error.